# programming atmega chip

Tags: atmega, atmel, programming

I have built a Ponyprog programmer to find out Windows 7 cannot recognize the drivers.

I was wondering if I could use this "[Pocket AVR Programmer](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825)" to program an atmega 8535?

If so, how do I connect the atmega to this board?

Or can you recommend something for me?

Answer (score 2):

From [Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825)

> This programmer works really well for
>   ATmega168 and ATmega328 and should
>   work with all the AVR micros supported
>   by AVRDUDE. We've played a bit with
>   the ATtinys but we cannot guarantee
>   that this board will be compatible
>   with anything but ATmega168/328.

From [Ladyada](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html) the ATMEGA8535 is listed as being supported by AVRDUDE.

And there is a pinout for the standard ISP connectors and an example schematic on how to hook it up at http://my.opera.com/CrazyTerabyte/blog/2008/02/02/first-contact-with-atmega8-microcontroller-part-4

Page 2 of your [data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2502.pdf) shows you the pin out of the chip. You will need to hook up all of these pins: reset, sck, miso, mosi, vcc(power), and ground

Comment: how do I connect the 8535 to this board? do i just plug in the first 6 pins or is the something I need to make up?

Comment: @Dale I added some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that on this [list](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/prjprog.html) you will be able to find simple and easy to build USB programmer for AVR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your programmer will do the job for all common atmega and attiny.

for atmel micro you have to connect this way :

```
programmer           target
GND         <->      GND
SCK         <->      SCK
MISO        <->      MISO
MOSI        <->      MOSI
RESET       <->      RESET
```

easy !

you can add VCC, if you want to power the target from the programmer (pay attention to the maximum of current it can provide)

they are two standart header (2x3 and 2x5), but I'm not using them in my personal design as they doesn't follow the common pinout of the atmega. I use a 1x5 header in the order i listed the connection because it is so much easier to route with less via and bigger trace ! I found it [with this programmer](http://tuxgraphics.org/electronics/200901/tuxgraphics-isp-header.shtml)

Also dont forget to put a pull up resistor on the reset line (~ 4k). You will also need one on MISO if you are using another SPI IC.

Comment: Doesn't reset have an internal pull-up?

Comment: I didn't see anything like this on the datasheet. As the reset pin can be use as general I/O, it has the generic pull up, but it's useless as you have to turn on the micro to activate it, and you need to activate it to turn on the micro...